# Is this an attributive clause or an adverbial clause?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, clauses

> **The radial-velocity method used** Dr Dumusque and his colleagues will
>   reveal the presence of a planet and its mass.

This sentence is from [an article at economist.com](http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2012/10/exoplanets), and it's the first sentence of paragraph 10. I only understand the main clause, but I don't know the function of "The radial-velocity method used". I want to know the structure of this sentence.

Comment: Too Localised. It's just a typo.

Comment: Read: "...method used ***by*** Dr Dumusque ...".

Answer (score 2):

It is not a clause of any sort, but a typographical error.  It should read

> The radial-velocity method used **by** Dr Dumusque and his colleagues will reveal the presence of a planet and its mass.

Interpreted (I have no reason to think that you will need this, but just to be on the safe side):

> The radial-velocity method ... which Dr. Dumusque and his colleagues use.

The radial-velocity method is described in paragraph 5; I assume it relies on a calculation of radial velocity to detect "the tiny wobble caused by the gravitational pull exerted by the planets that circle" a star.